# Get data from a file based on certain text - Python

Tags: python, list, file

I have a data that comes in the below format in a file.

```
"Attach Listener" #7338 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f51c0009000 nid=0x731c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"lettuce-nioEventLoop-9-155" #362 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f515000c800 nid=0x4f7c runnable [0x00007f50da85d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x0000000082af6f50> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
    - locked <0x0000000082af8050> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x0000000082af7f78> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:62)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:753)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:409)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"lettuce-nioEventLoop-9-154" #360 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f51d00c3800 nid=0x4dd5 runnable [0x00007f50da45b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x0000000082afa8b0> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
    - locked <0x0000000082afb9b0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x0000000082afb8d8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:62)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:753)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:409)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" #7338 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f51c0009000 nid=0x731c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

I need to store the complete stack trace based on the first line of each stack. i.e. **"lettuce-nioEventLoop-9-155" #362 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f515000c800 nid=0x4f7c runnable [0x00007f50da85d000]**

I need to collect the first lines of each trace and when I compare with the data i have to the data in the file and if it matches, i need to collect the complete trace of that. There may be cases where the first line might be same for some other stack trace in the same file, and if that is the case, i need to append it to the same already collected data previously.

This is what I've done -

```
data_methods = []
tdfilename = r"C:\Users\hello\Desktop\trace_test.txt"
with open(tdfilename) as f:
    for line in f:
        method = re.findall(r'"(.*?)]', line)
        fmethod = ''.join(method)
        if fmethod:
            data_methods.append("\""+fmethod+"]") # Adding " and ] at the start and end of the line as per the file content
f.close()
```

I'm collecting the first lines of all the stack traces into a list. My idea here is to compare this list data with the data in the file and if it matches, i need to collect the complete trace. I'm stuck on getting the logic for this.

Should i be using `dict` to save the first line as keys and the content as values as the firsts lines can occur multiple times with the same data?

How can i achieve this. I'm doing this to ease some of our work in our daily activities.

Comment: *"... as the keys can be repetitive ?"*. No, they can't.

Comment: sorry, my bad. updated the question. I meant, since the first lines of the stack traces can occur multiple times and can be seam, i need to append the data to the same one.

Comment: This data looks like a log. If you need to process a large amount of logs, It might be a good idea to use the ELK stack, you may use python interface as well.
https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack

Comment: thanks for the idea. this is a dump file with little data and doesn't get generated often . I'm planning to achieve this using Python itself as rest of my other codes are in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `defaultdict` can be handy when you want to create a new *thing* in a mapping and add to it if it already exists. Here I would just do:

```
data_methods = collections.defaultdict(list)
tdfilename = r"C:\Users\hello\Desktop\trace_test.txt"
firstpattern = re.compile(r'".*]\s*$')
with open(tdfilename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if firstpattern.match(line)
        cur = data_methods[line.strip()]
    else:
        cur.append(line)
```

You have then just to join the values, for example to dump the result:

```
for k, v in data_methods.items():
    print(k)
    print(''.join(v))
```

Comment: Serge, you have mentioned `cur` as a string and also a list. is that correct? also for `data_methods.items:` line of code, i see `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`, should we add anything here ?

Comment: It should have been `data_methods.items()` (fixed). For the first point, `cur` is a list of lines, the reason why I use `join` to concatenate it. Python is usualy better at adding lines to a list than repeatedly concatenating to a string.

Comment: Thanks Serge! i was able to modify this according to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can rely on the indentation in the trace format. So this is a basic version:

```
td_filename = 'trace.txt'

exc_dict = {}

with open(td_filename) as f:
    cur_line = None

    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(' ') or line.startswith('\n'):
            if cur_line is not None:
                exc_dict[cur_line].append(line)
        else:
            if line not in exc_dict:
                exc_dict[line] = []
            cur_line = line

for k in exc_dict:
    print(k)
    print(exc_dict[k])
    print('\n')
```

If you want to separate the individual exceptions and join the strings, try this:

```
td_filename = 'trace.txt'

exc_dict = {}

with open(td_filename) as f:
    cur_line = None

    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(' ') or line.startswith('\n'):
            if cur_line is not None:
                if exc_dict[cur_line][-1] is None:
                    exc_dict[cur_line][-1] = ''
                exc_dict[cur_line][-1] += line
        else:
            if line not in exc_dict:
                exc_dict[line] = []

            exc_dict[line].append(None)
            cur_line = line

for k in exc_dict:
    print(k)
    for e in exc_dict[k]:
        print(e)
        print('\n')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it is splitting up each line into one element making more lines of data

Comment: I added and alternative where the strings are joined.

Comment: Hello, sure thank you.. i will git it a try and let you know..appreciate your help.